# Swift protocol extension `var { get }` override implementation's `let`

Tags: swift, overriding, protocols, protocol-extension

Implementing property with `var` and `let` behaves differently when the implementing struct is assigned to a variable typed as `protocol`.

```
protocol Req {
  var path: String? { get }
}
extension Req {
  var path: String? { return "Req" }
}

struct LetReq: Req {
  let path = "LetReq"
}
struct VarReq: Req {
  var path: String? { return "VarReq" }
}

var req: Req!

req = VarReq()
req.path // prints "VarReq"

req = LetReq()
req.path // prints "Req" not "LetReq" which seems very awkward.
```

Is this designed behaviour of Swift?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a compiler bug. If you make a `LetReq` an optional string, it works as expected:

```
struct LetReq: Req {
    let path: String? = "LetReq"
}
```

[File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I think that behavior is correct.

```
struct LetReq: Req {
    let path = "LetReq"
}
```

path is `String` type not `String?`

```
var req: Req!
req = LetReq()
req.path
```

`req` is type of `Req`. So `req.path` means type is `String?` and name is `path`

`Req`'s extension has default variable for `path` variable. so `req.path` refer that variable not `LetReq`'s `path`

Answer (score 0):

It's vague... But I would bet on a bug.

At least for current implementation(`swiftc` 2.2);

1. Swift supports method overloading by only different return types.
2. But only for methods, not properties.
3. So, all properties must have different names.

This can be proven by this.

```
struct AA {
    func a() -> String { return "" }
    func a() -> String? { return "" }
    var b: String { return "" }
    var b: String? { return "" } // Error: Invalid redeclaraion of `b`.
}
```

But anyway, the compiler doesn't seem to check this redeclaration by protocol extension. So, `LetReq` instance actually provides two properties.

```
var path: String { get }
var path: String? { get }
```

You can check this with this.

```
print(LetReq().path as String?)    // prints `Optional("Req")`.
print(LetReq().path as String)     // prints `LetReq`.
```

I believe this kind of property overloading must be prevented by compiler. For same reason of why they prevented property overloading in `struct AA`. So, that's a bug in my opinion.